# How to insert superscript characters (e.g: 2^2) in HTML?

Tags: html

As the title says, is it possible in HTML (or with special characters) to type for example: 2^2 so the square is smaller and placed at the top.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: Do you *really* want just 2²? I find that hard to believe. If you generally want superscripts, then the question would be too broad really, and one that has been asked several times at SO. If you have some specific use for superscripts in a specific context, you should describe that, if problems remain after studying general advice on different ways of using superscripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [superscript](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sup.asp) tag.

```
2<sup>2</sup>
```

This outputs 2<sup>2</sup>

Comment: I just tested this answer with NVDA (a screenreader) and it reads as "twenty two", which obviously isn't the desired result. So **be careful** doing this if you care about accessibility, which you should. So using `2&sup2;` might be better as it at least reads "two superscript two" (because `&sup2;` [is a different character entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25938710/486434)). Results might differ in different screenreaders, though.

Answer (score 12):

It's called *Superscript* and there's a slight **difference** in it's use with a `<sup>` tag and directly using the Unicode Character called "**Superscript Two**":

HTML Tag: `2<sup>2</sup>`  2<sup>2</sup>

HTML entity: *(see the difference)* `2&sup2;`  2²

```
Encodings :

HTML Entity (decimal)              &#178;
HTML Entity (hex)                  &#xb2;
HTML Entity (named)                &sup2;
Windows                            Alt +B2
                                   Alt 0178
                                   Alt 253
UTF-8  (hex)                       0xC2 0xB2 (c2b2)
UTF-8  (binary)                    11000010:10110010
UTF-16 (hex)                       0x00B2 (00b2)
UTF-16 (decimal)                   178
UTF-32 (hex)                       0x000000B2 (b2)
UTF-32 (decimal)                   178
C/C++/Java source code             "\u00B2"
Python source code                 u"\u00B2"
```

<sup>[Fileformat link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm)</sup>

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

Comment: The superscript 2 character and the normal 2 character in superscript style are different beasts, not just slightly different.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `&sup2;` html entity:

```
2&sup2;
```

It will be displayed as "2²".

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
2<sup>2</sup>
```

Comment: Or even `2&sup2;` for a tidier result.

Comment: Cool, I didn't realize that was an HTML entity.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "superscript 2" unicode character (HTML entity &#178; or &sup2;), e.g.

```
<p>2&#178;</p>
```

It looks like this:

2²

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `<sup>` tag which is used for superscripts. Alternatively if you wanted more control you could use a span with a special style and an offset of relative.

**HTML (Example)**

```
<div>2<span class="superscript">2</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.superscript {
    font-size: 0.4em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}
```

You can see this example working in JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7vq82tdv/1/).

Comment: This is not elegant and there are more appropriate ways to display superscript in HTML (e.g.: `&sup2;`).

Answer (score 1):

Using MathML,

```html
<math>
  <msup>
    <mn>2</mn>
    <mn>2</mn>
  </msup>
</math>
```

Comment: *... if browser supports it*

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, it's a shame, not all browsers support it, even though MathML 2.0 is a W3C Recommendation since 21 October 2003.